# How to use HTML for the interface and Python for the inner workings

Tags: python, html, css

I've been working with a friend on a QR code reader projet. We're working mainly in Python, but wanted to know if there was a way to build the UI and the general website using HTML&CSS while using Python for the scanning of the QR code, because of how complicated building interfaces in python is with my skill.

Is there a way to "import" the Python so that it can be used in combination with HTML and CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a very popular way of using python with HTML and CSS. Its called Django.
[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/)

You can write your code in python and use it in your webpages. But if you mean using python as a JavaScript alternative I don't think there's a convenient way of doing that.

Comment: Do you know exactly how you can implement Python using Django?

Comment: Django is a python framework. So "IMPLEMENTING" isn't gonna be a problem as it works on python. You should check out tutorials on YouTube. Django isn't that hard to learn. And Once you get the basics you can easily combine your python codes with HTML and CSS.